# Purple theme for "Bash On Ubuntu On Windows" for Windows 10

Tags: command-line, themes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I have the cool purple theme as in Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04 in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?
This is what I have:
[image]

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1128269/bash-on-windows-10-is-there-way-to-apply-themes-like-solarized-to-cmd

Comment: What do you mean by "on Ubuntu on Windows"?

Comment: @HaydenStites updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: So this is a Windows program which allows you to use the Ubuntu Bash?

Comment: @HaydenStites - Yes, see bash on windows - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about . It is supported by Ubuntu thus "ubuntu on windows" so to speak. To theme it you need to theme the windows command prompt, see linky I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introduction

You can setup Ubuntu like colors in Windows Subsystem for Linux as [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jgarijogarde/make-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10-look-like-the-ubuntu-terminal-f7566008c5c2) describes in detail:

[image: wsl with standard screenfetch.png]

### Caveat

Don't use the `screenfetch` display above, use the modified `winscreeny` [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978977/windows-subsystem-for-linux-display-linux-distribution/978978?r=SearchResults#978978):

[image: WSL bash startup.png]

Using this splash screen gives more details than the tutorial's screen and avoids error messages like it has.

### Terminal Background Color Instruction Summary

To summarize the tutorial in the first link you will need to:

- Head to the Ubuntu Website to download the Ubuntu Font for free.
- Install these fonts by clicking the “Install” button in the Windows Font Viewer windows. **NOTE:** I found the Consola's font built into Windows the best for me.
- Change the default terminal colors as per table below.
- Slot 1: `Red: 78, Green: 154, Blue: 6`
- Slot 2: `Red: 52, Green: 101, Blue: 164`
- Slot 3: `Red: 48, Green: 10, Blue: 36`
- Slot 4: `Red: 6, Green: 152, Blue: 154`
- Slot 5: `Red: 204, Green: 0, Blue: 0`
- Slot 6: `Red: 117, Green: 80, Blue: 123`
- Slot 7: `Red: 196, Green: 160, Blue: 0`
- Slot 8: `Red: 211, Green: 215, Blue: 207`
- Slot 9: `Red: 85, Green: 87, Blue: 83`
- Slot 10: `Red: 114, Green: 159, Blue: 207`
- Slot 11: `Red: 138, Green: 226, Blue: 52`
- Slot 12: `Red: 52, Green: 226, Blue: 226`
- Slot 13: `Red: 239, Green: 41, Blue: 41`
- Slot 14: `Red: 173, Green: 127, Blue: 168`
- Slot 15: `Red: 252, Green: 233, Blue: 79`
- Slot 16: `Red: 238, Green: 238, Blue: 238`

As Piotr Bartnicki notes, many people may prefer a lighter blue for directories. If you fall into this camp, put the value for slot 10 in slot 2.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of turning some of the comments into an answer.

"Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" is a colaborative project between Canonical and Microsoft

> Overview
>
> Bash on Windows provides developers with a familiar Bash shell and
>   Linux environment in which you can run most Linux command-line tools,
>   directly on Windows, UNMODIFIED, without needing an entire Linux
>   virtual machine!
>
> Bash/WSL allows you to:
>
> Run common command-line utilities such as grep, sed, awk, etc. Use the
>   Linux-compatible filesystem & hierarchy and access fixed Windows
>   storage mounted under /mnt/... Run Bash shell scripts and Linux
>   command-line apps. including Tools: vim, emacs, tmux Languages:
>   Javascript/node.js, Ruby, Python, C/C++, C# & F#, Rust, Go, etc.
>   Services: sshd, MySQL, Apache, lighttpd, Install additional Linux
>   tools using apt Invoke Windows applications from within Bash Invoke
>   Linux applications from within Windows!
>
> **Bash on Windows runs Ubuntu user-mode binaries provided by Canonical. This means the command-line utilities are the same as those that run within a native Ubuntu environment.**

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq for additional details.

But theming the bash environment is the same as theming the Windows command prompt. There are *some* themes available, see https://github.com/neilpa/cmd-colors-solarized

[image: dark]

[image: Light]

BUT the Ubuntu purple theme is not available yet.

Further discussion here - https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/880