# Changing the terminal font colors while running linux(ubuntu) in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: color-management, powershell

I'm running ubuntu through the Windows PowerShell. The path is in a blue color which is very difficult to read. How can the colors of the fonts, backgrounds, foregrounds be changed?

Comment: Duplicate - https://askubuntu.com/questions/922425/purple-theme-for-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-for-windows-10/922432

Comment: That links needs an upvote if it is used to mark as duplicate.

Comment: You are using WSL, right?

Comment: @Terrance - That does not work for Bash on Windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about

Comment: @bodhi.zazen comment removed.

Comment: @Terrance - Too bad, sort of a good reference for others.

Comment: This might help:  https://askubuntu.com/a/466203/231142

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you started bash from a consolehost running powershell with it's own colorscheme.

If you'd used `start bash` or `Start-Process bash.exe` you'd got the colors set in the properties for bash

Microsoft just prereleased a [Windows Console Colortool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/08/11/introducing-the-windows-console-colortool/?WT.mc_id=AID640961_EML_5203907) (coming with fall update) which helps with colorpalettes and IIUR you'll be able to import palettes from other sources.

Comment: I don't think it is off topic at all as this is Canonical completely supports this venture http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/03/ubuntu-on-windows.html

Comment: The issue is Windows uses a different mechanism to provide colors, bash on windows is new and in development. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/922425/purple-theme-for-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-for-windows-10/922432