# Windows Subsystem for Linux display Linux distribution?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ascii

There is the package [screenfetch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenfetch) to display your Ubuntu distribution from the CLI with an ASCII splash screen:

[image: WSL Bash screenfetch]

There is also a package called [WinScreeny](https://github.com/nijikokun/WinScreeny) that will display a Windows logo when running Linux in a Windows environment but doesn't support WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Is there a way to display an ASCII CLI Linux Distribution splash screen in WSL that reflects the Windows logo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### WinScreeny

I took one of the three [Github WinScreeny](https://github.com/nijikokun/WinScreeny) bash scripts and modified it  to look like this:

[image: WSL bash startup.png]

Here is the modified code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Windows Screenfetch (Without the Screenshot functionality)
# Hacked together by Nijikokun <nijikokun@gmail.com> 
# License: AOL <aol.nexua.org>

# Downloaded from: https://github.com/nijikokun/WinScreeny
# Modified from Windows to Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu initially)

version='0.4'

# Displayment
display=( Host Cpu OS Arch Shell Motherboard HDD Memory Uptime Resolution DE WM WMTheme Font )

# Color Loop
bld=$'\e[1m'
rst=$'\e[0m'
inv=$'\e[7m'
und=$'\e[4m'
f=3 b=4
for j in f b; do
  for i in {0..7}; do
    printf -v $j$i %b "\e[${!j}${i}m"
  done
done

# Debugging
debug=

Debug () {
    echo -e "\e[1;31m:: \e[0m$1"
}

# Flag Check
while getopts "vVh" flags; do
    case $flags in
        h)
            echo -e "${und}Usage${rst}:"
            echo -e "  screeny [Optional Flags]"
            echo ""
            echo "WinScreeny - A CLI Bash Script to show System Information for Windows!"
            echo ""
            echo -e "${und}Options${rst}:"
            echo -e "    ${bld}-v${rst}                 Verbose / Debug Output"
            echo -e "    ${bld}-V${rst}                 Display script version"
            echo -e "    ${bld}-h${rst}                 Display this file"
            exit;;
        V)
            echo -e "${und}WinScreeny${rst} - Version ${version}"
            echo -e "Copyright (C) Nijiko Yonskai (nijikokun@gmail.com)"
            echo ""
            echo -e "This is free software, under the AOL license: http://aol.nexua.org"
            echo -e "Source can be downloaded from: https://github.com/Nijikokun/WinScreeny"
            exit;;
        v) debug=1 continue;;
    esac
done

# Prevent Unix Output
unameOutput=`uname`GARBAGE
if [[ "$unameOutput" == 'Linux' ]] || [[ "$unameOutput" == 'Darwin' ]] ; then
    echo 'This script is for Windows, silly!'
    exit 0
fi

# Begin Detection
detectHost () {
    user=$(echo "$USER")
    host=$(hostname)
    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding hostname, and user.... Found as: '$user@$host'"
}

detectCpu () {
    cpu=$(awk -F':' '/model name/{ print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo | head -n 1 | tr -s " " | sed 's/^ //')
    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding cpu.... Found as: '$cpu'"
}

detectOS () {
    os=`uname -r`
}

detectArch () {
    arch=`lsb_release -a 2>&1 | awk '{ print $2 " " $3 " " $4}' | head -3 | tail -1`
    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding Architecture.... Found as: '$arch'"
}

detectHDD () {
    size=`df -H |  awk '{ print $2}' | head -2 | tail -1 | tr -d '\r '`
    free=`df -H |  awk '{ print $4 }' | head -2 | tail -1 | tr -d '\r '`

}

detectResolution () {
    width=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem/WMIC.exe desktopmonitor get screenwidth | grep -vE '[a-z]+' | tr -d '\r\n '`
    height=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem/WMIC.exe desktopmonitor get screenheight | grep -vE '[a-z]+' | tr -d '\r\n '`
}

detectUptime () {
    uptime=`awk -F. '{print $1}' /proc/uptime`
    secs=$((${uptime}%60))
    mins=$((${uptime}/60%60))
    hours=$((${uptime}/3600%24))
    days=$((${uptime}/86400))
    uptime="${mins}m"

    if [ "${hours}" -ne "0" ]; then
      uptime="${hours}h ${uptime}"
    fi

    if [ "${days}" -ne "0" ]; then
      uptime="${days}d ${uptime}"
    fi

    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding Uptime.... Found as: '$uptime${rst}'"
}

detectMemory () {
    total_mem=$(awk '/MemTotal/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo)
    totalmem=$((${total_mem}/1024))
    free_mem=$(awk '/MemFree/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo)
    used_mem=$((${total_mem} - ${free_mem}))
    usedmem=$((${used_mem}/1024))
    mem="${usedmem}MB / ${totalmem}MB"

    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding Memory.... Found as: '$mem${rst}'"
}

detectShell () {
    myshell=`bash --version | head -1`
    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding Shell.... Found as: '$myshell'"
}

detectMotherboard () {
    board=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem/WMIC.exe baseboard get product | tail -2 | tr -d '\r '`
}

detectDE () {
    winver=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem/WMIC.exe os get version | grep -o '^[0-9]'`
    if [ "$winver" == "7" ]; then
        de='Aero'
    elif [ "$winver" == "6" ]; then
        de='Aero'
    else
        de=$winver
    fi
    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding Desktop Environment.... Found as: '$de'"
}

detectWM () {
    vcxsrv=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/tasklist.exe | grep -o 'vcxsrv' | tr -d '\r \n'`
    wind=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/tasklist.exe | grep -o 'Windawesome' | tr -d '\r \n'`
    if [ "$vcxsrv" = "vcxsrv" ]; then
        wm="VcXsrv"
    elif [ "$wind" = "Windawesome" ]; then
        wm="Windawesome"
    else
        wm="DWM"
    fi
    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding Window Manager.... Found as: '$wm'"
}

detectWMTheme () {
    themeFile="$(/mnt/c/Windows/System32/reg.exe query 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes' /v 'CurrentTheme' | grep -o '[A-Z]:\\.*')"
#   theme=$(echo $themeFile | awk -F"\\" '{print $NF}' | grep -o '[0-9A-z. ]*$' | grep -o '^[0-9A-z ]*')
    theme=$themeFile
    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding Window Theme.... Found as: '$theme'"
}

detectFont () {
#   font=$(cat $HOME/.minttyrc | grep '^Font=.*' | grep -o '[0-9A-Za-z ]*$')
    font="Consolas"
    [[ "$debug" -eq "1" ]] && Debug "Finding Font.... Found as: '$font'"
#   if [ -z $font ]; then
#       font="Lucida Console"
#   fi
}

# Loops :>
for i in "${display[@]}"; do
    [[ "${display[*]}" =~ "$i" ]] && detect${i}
done

# Output

cat << EOF

$f1         ,.=:^!^!t3Z3z.,                
$f1        :tt:::tt333EE3                  ${f6}${user}${f7}@${f6}${host}
$f1        Et:::ztt33EEE  $f2@Ee.,      ..,   
$f1       ;tt:::tt333EE7 $f2;EEEEEEttttt33#   ${f6}OS: ${f7}${os} ${arch}
$f1      :Et:::zt333EEQ.$f2 SEEEEEttttt33QL   ${f6}CPU: ${f7}${cpu}
$f1      it::::tt333EEF $f2@EEEEEEttttt33F    ${f6}HDD free / size: ${f7}$free / $size
$f1     ;3=*^\`\`\`'*4EEV $f2:EEEEEEttttt33@.    ${f6}Memory used / size: ${f7}${mem}
$f4     ,.=::::it=., $f1\` $f2@EEEEEEtttz33QF     ${f6}Uptime: ${f7}$uptime
$f4    ;::::::::zt33)   $f2'4EEEtttji3P*      ${f6}Resolution: ${f7}$width x $height
$f4   :t::::::::tt33.$f3:Z3z..  $f2\`\` $f3,..g.      ${f6}Motherboard: ${f7}$board
$f4   i::::::::zt33F$f3 AEEEtttt::::ztF       ${f6}Shell: ${f7}$myshell
$f4  ;:::::::::t33V $f3;EEEttttt::::t3        ${f6}DE: ${f7}$de
$f4  E::::::::zt33L $f3@EEEtttt::::z3F        ${f6}WM: ${f7}$wm
$f4 {3=*^\`\`\`'*4E3) $f3;EEEtttt:::::tZ\`        ${f6}WM Theme: ${f7}$theme
$f4             \` $f3:EEEEtttt::::z7          ${f6}Font: ${f7}$font
$f3                 $f3'VEzjt:;;z>*\`        $rst

EOF
```

I won't spend a lot of time dissecting it but you will notice it's a hybrid of some Linux kernel stuff and some Windows kernel stuff.

For example this Linux kernel line displays your CPU information:

```
cpu=$(awk -F':' '/model name/{ print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo | head -n 1 | tr -s " " | sed 's/^ //')
```

On the other hand this Windows kernel line displays your motherboard model:

```
board=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem/WMIC.exe baseboard get product | tail -2 | tr -d '\r '`
```

---

### Weather, Calendar and Time

Some people like the top part of the Ubuntu Bash on Windows 10 (WSL) terminal splash screen. If you would like the Weather, Calendar and current Time to display you can find the instructions here: [How can I get this terminal splash screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/how-can-i-get-this-terminal-splash-screen/1020693#1020693)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75409/discussion-on-answer-by-wineunuuchs2unix-windows-subsystem-for-linux-display-lin).