# Mistyped <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<T> split existing terminal window

Tags: 16.04, command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

For years now I've been using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new terminal window. Just now for the first time it took my existing window and created two panes within it:

[image: now.png]

^^ *New terminal session with `~/.bashrc` start up commands showing date, time and system information. ie No commands run yet*

I must have hit a different key combination as I just tried it again double checking as I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and a new window as normal.

As I might want to utilize this feature in the future, What key combination did I use?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T opens a new tab in terminal

Comment: @Terrance I blame the beer; ) Care to post an answer so I can accept it? Or...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open a tab in terminal press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> key combination.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to follow up, I use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`T` all the time now. One of those rare instances where an accident turns out positive.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That's good to hear!  :)  BTW, your terminal looks really good when you open it up!  I like the colors and fonts you are using.  Nice job!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. The screen was out of date because PerlDuck gave me tips on getting the weather on the splash screen. So I've just posted a new screen shot. The Ubuntu under Windows 10 splash screen looks even cooler I think.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I think you should open a new Q&A showing how you did that.  I would totally upvote!  =)

Comment: I already had a Ubuntu on Windows 10 [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978977/windows-subsystem-for-linux-display-linux-distribution) but it isn't detailed enough with code and doesn't target Ubuntu on Ubuntu (sounds weird I know). I want to adjust widget screen spacing and extend the PS1 line prompt separator before I post a new self answered Q&A.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Looks good so far, but really looking forward to your updates my friend!  =)

Comment: I've posted a new Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/how-can-i-get-this-gnome-terminal-splash-screen/1020693#1020693