# Installing Hindi on Window Subsystem Terminal

Tags: fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, language-support

I have tried

```
sudo apt install fonts-indic
```

However Hindi still shows up as
[image]

```
{ name: 'स्वास््य एवं स्वचछता',
```

It suppose to show up as above.

When I copy and paste, they show up fine.

Comment: I had to try all the font family names until I found one (Condolas I think?) that `toilet` displayed line draw characters properly for the current time. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/978977/windows-subsystem-for-linux-display-linux-distribution/978978#978978 So my first suggestion would be to try all the font family names available in WSL terminal that are close to your selection.

Comment: I don't find any fond named Condolas. Is it Consolas? Can you also share a link?

Comment: Probably Consolas then. I'm not suggesting that font would work for you. I'm only saying I had to try every single available font until I found one that worked for me. The other thing to consider is you might have to install Windows fonts, not just Ubuntu fonts to achieve your objectives.

Comment: None of them shows correctly. Any set of fonts you suggest for me to install that WSL support?